# Error: ./ts3server: not found

Tags: docker

I'm trying to make an Teamspeak image running on Alpine linux but am honest not sure why docker says

```
./ts3server: not found
```

This is the Github page with the Dockerfile code:
https://github.com/signofkoen/docker-teamspeak/blob/snapshot/Dockerfile

Container log:

```
/opt/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh: line 8: ./ts3server: not found
```

Anyone know's what am doing wrong? I think a did something wrong with the extracting part but am not sure.

Comment: Why are you running `./ts3server`?  When your container starts, your working directory is `/`, and it's unlikely that the `ts3server` is installed there.

Comment: @larsks I'm not running ./ts3server the teamspeak startup script runs that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ts3server` binary in your image looks like it was built against `glibc`, but it is unable to find the appropriate runtime loader on the filesystem.

You can see this by running `ldd /opt/teamspeak/ts3server`, which reports:

```
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:
No such file or directory (needed by ts3server)
```

This is the direct cause of your error.

I see that you're starting with the `skardoska/alpine-glibc` image, which sounds like maybe it was designed to provide a standard glibc environment to Alpine linux, but the image does not appear to have been constructed in a way that is compatible with your binaries.  Looking at the description at https://hub.docker.com/r/skardoska/alpine-glibc/, it appears this may be a known problem, because the description says, "Waiting for https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/1".

You may be better off just starting with a glibc based distribution like Fedora or Ubuntu.